# Need help on deciding right way to store the each character of a text

Tags: c#

So here is the deal. Suppose i have a ".txt" file which contains some kind of text(any). I need a program to read each character in the text including symbols, numbers, white space and etc. After I need it to count amount of occurrence of each character that was read.

Now reading text char by char is easy:

```
 string text = File.ReadAllText("text.txt");
 foreach (char c in text) Console.WriteLine(c);
```

What will be the best way to save each character from a .txt file and work with them after?

Comment: As every character needs to be evaluated, use [File.ReadLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of File.ReadAllText. ReadLines will read the lines in 1 by 1 and can be evaluated as each line is read, where as ReadAllText will read the entire file content into the string variable which is then evaluated only after the entire file is read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need the characters as well as the number of occurrence of the appearing characters. Consider of using `Dictionary<char,int>` to help you:

```
Dictionary<char,int> dict = new Dictionary<char,int>();
for (char c in text){
    if (dict.ContainsKey(c)) //exist add count of the existing item
        dict[c] = dict[c] + 1;
    else //does not exist, create new item
        dict.Add(c,1);
}
```

By using `Dictionary`, you could do things like these, which seem to fit your needs best:

```
dict.Keys; //to get all characters (Keys) you store in the dictionary before
dict.ContainsKey('a'); //to check if the Dictionary has 'a' as one of its keys
dict['a']; //to get the value dictionary item with character 'a' as its Key
dict.Add('a',1); //add new key 'a' to the dictionary with the value of 1
```

Comment: Your answer seems to fit the needs. Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @Lenny ah yes... as the name `Dictionary` suggests. :) you could figure out more about `Dictionary`, and at some point, you may also want to learn about `List`. Both are very useful classes to know. :) checkout `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: So as I understood after toying with them. In my particular situation Dictionary class is more suitable and comfortable. However, I have question about efficiency when working with big amount of data. Which one will be more efficient List or Dictionary?

Comment: @Lenny hmm... as long as you access one by one, I would suggest to use `Dictionary`

Comment: Thought so. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I would say using List would work in this case.